# I want to travel out off schengen area with visa d germany?

Tags: transit-visas, kosovo

I have a visa d germany
Valid for Deutschland    and Mult  entry
For 90 days until 01.09.2019
Can i travel out off schengen area i want to go too Kosovo and back again,but kosovo is out off schengen area and out off europe can i travel to kosovo with bus or not?!

Comment: You should blank out your personal details before posting a picture of your visa. What is your citizenship?

Comment: I am Kosovar citizenship

Comment: As you note yourself the visa is good for _multiple entries_. What would be the problem?

Comment: It can take some time to get your residence permit, so you should start this process as soon as you arrive in Germany.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your *multiple-entry* visa you can come and go in the Schengen Area as many times as you like. Just make sure that you do not spend more than 90 days in total in the Schengen Area and that you do not stay beyond the validity period.

Your visa type D is valid for Germany, but allows for visits to the other Schengen States, with the possible exception of Spain, that does not recognise Kosovo as an independent state. You can therefore transit trough several countries without an additional visa. While not in the Schengen Area yet, Croatia will also accept your German visa.

Bosnia-Herzegovina will require a specific visa and Serbia will not accept a Kosovan passport.

Comment: can I get back from hungary in the schengen area by bus because the visa is writing valid for deutschland can that be a problem or i have to enter schengen with plane in germany??

Comment: @NazmiMehani: The visa allows for transit through other Schengen states.

Comment: Note that the 90-day rule does not count days spent _in the country that issued the D visa_.

Comment: So i dont have any problem if i left schengen area with this visa and back again?